# Any way to avoid capture cache in Smarty 2?

Tags: smarty, smarty2

I have some captured content displayed on page more than once which I need to prevent from being cached because the second time it gets wrong values rendered. I have learned that in Smarty 3, there is the new {nocache} block and nocache flag available to prevent caching of variables which I believe could help me in this case. Is there any alternative to do the same in Smarty 2 or the only way is to upgrade to Smarty 3 to get this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [caching section of the Smarty2 Documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/caching.tpl), they describe some possibilities on how to cope with this:

> You can keep parts of a page dynamic with the [insert](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.insert.tpl) template
>   function. Let's say the whole page can be cached except for a banner
>   that is displayed down the side of the page. By using the [insert](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.insert.tpl)
>   function for the banner, you can keep this element dynamic within the
>   cached content.

Another way would be to just clear the cache of your specific template before displaying it:

```
require('Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty;
...
$smarty->clear_cache('your_template_without_cache.tpl');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to avoid editing PHP files. I've to do this on tpl level only. E.g. I got a page and on top I got some links rendered via this tpl code for each item:
`{capture "foo" assign="trfoo"}{plugin _name="include" page="item$ID"}{/plugin}{/capture}
<a href="#item{$ID}" class="perex" title="{$trfoo|striptags|truncate:240}">{$itemTitle}</a>`

Then I have other dynamic content included in the page via other tpl:
`{capture "foo2" assign="trfoo2"}{plugin _name="include" page="item$ID"}{/plugin}{/capture}<p class="preview">{$trfoo2|truncate:760}</p>`

Problem is the cached $ID in 2nd.

Comment: Then use the insert template function as described in my reply.